# htaccess remove part of the url

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls structured like this:

```
 /!#/pretty-url/
```

I need to remove the !# so the urls will look like this:

```
/pretty-url/
```

What would be the correct .htaccess rule to do this?

Comment: And "!#" is what? A folder name or something?

Comment: i think "!#" is for some javascript. i don't think that what you want to do will work.

Comment: @Nux `#` is always either the fragment separator or part of the fragment. And the fragment is not embedded in the requested URL.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was wondering what was it spoused and why the links are structured like that. But yes, you can't redirect server side with things that are not send to the server.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a # in the URL then that is a named anchor. The browser does not send anything to the right of a # to the server. This means that all the rewrite engine is seeing is:-

```
/!
```

If you want your URLs to look like this then you are going to need to use JavaScript to get the relevant content via AJAX.

Comment: BTW. You can use [History.js][1] to avoid problems with Hashbangs and the need of JS redirects.

  [1]: https://github.com/balupton/History.js/